# Express.IO connection keeps failing with HTTP 500

Tags: ios, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using Express.IO and [This iOS Client](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) trying to create a basic socket example but I can't seem to be able to connect.

I tried everything I could possibly find on google but everytime my client tries connecting I get the following error:

`2013-08-12 14:48:42.628 SocketIOTest[59835:c07] ERROR: handshake failed ... Could not connect to the server.
2013-08-12 14:48:42.628 SocketIOTest[59835:c07] OnError: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo=0x7594570 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:7076/socket.io/1/?t=16807, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:7076/socket.io/1/?t=16807, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSUnderlyingError=0x10967bb0 "Could not connect to the server."}`

When I go to `http://localhost:7076/socket.io/1/?t=16807` in my browser I get this response:
`ttIwyz7Tw6uFjp00WceI:60:60:websocket,htmlfile,xhr-polling,jsonp-polling`

But for some reason when checking with header tools, it actually does return an HTTP 500 error. I'm really not sure why.

Here's my Node code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var express     = require('express.io');
var app         = express().http().io();
var redisStore  = require('connect-redis')(express);

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
                            store:  new redisStore({
                                        host:   '192.168.33.10',
                                        port:   6386
                                    }),
                            secret: 'A>mVt*Cx87Kq^9:3}am$q67JYtGGAl'
                        })) ;

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Cookie');
    next();
});

app.set( 'origins', '*' );

app.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connection");
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
});

app.listen(7076);
console.log('App API Server is listening on port 7076');
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are referring to localhost:  `NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:7076/socket.io/1/?t=16807` in your IOS client, while the node.js server is running on some external Linux box.
Try connecting to the server instead.

Comment: Its a VM on the same address and my iOS client can connect to a regular Socket.IO ... I'm not sure what's wrong with Express.IO - that's what i'm trying to understand.

Comment: If it is running in VM, are you sure that localhost refers to the correct IP address? Could you tell more about the setup. Is the IOS client running on an IOS device?

Comment: Yup, as I said - I can connect with no problem when talking about a Socket.IO service, but when trying this code in Express.IO it doesnt. It actually shows the correct data in the URL i posted above but it returns HTTP 500 instead of 200 OK.